# The easy and modern way to manage the changes of a java project on a deployment server

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

This is i am writing doubting that whether the method i am using outdated or not. I have a java webserver and usually i will have changes on and when i need to upload the changes i will build the project locally and upload java files and restart.

The other method is upload war file completely and place into webapps folder. In this case if there is any dynamic images or files uploaded by users, i need to take a backup and replaced with the newly created folder after the war file deployment.

Is the both above are good method or anybody can suggest me an even more good method to manage my live environment changes.

Comment: Use WAR file built with Jenkins. Store your "dynamic" files outside of our webapp folder: somewhere else on the machine, or in a database.  Alternatively, look at Spring Boot, which uses an executable JAR file with Tomcat wrapped up inside it, rather than having to deploy a WAR into an existing tomcat.

Comment: Oh i think storing the files outside webapp is a good option. I am not that much familiar with jenkins but i will check it. Thank you for your answer.